# how can I override priority between paths of /bin and /usr/local/bin?

Tags: command-line, system, paths

Today I wanted to run `ss -tpla` command to see network connections, to my surprize I got `error: unknown option -t`. Then I checked location of `ss` command:

```
 ~$ whereis ss
 ss: /bin/ss /usr/local/bin/ss /usr/share/man/man8/ss.8.gz
```

As you see I have two `ss` commands, one in `/bin/ss` and the other in `/usr/local/bin/ss`.

I might have installed another application with the same name from source code into `/usr/local/bin/ss`. I don't remember when and usage of it but it's not the command I want to run. Strange thing is that when I  run

```
 ss -tpla
```

it redirects the command to `/usr/local/bin/ss`
I can run actual `ss` command with

```
 /bin/ss  -tpla
```

I thought `/bin` has the priority over other paths.

My question is what determines priorities of system paths and how I can override them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give `/bin/ss` priority by creating a symbolic link to it.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/ss
sudo ln -s /bin/ss /opt/ss/
```

and add `/opt/ss` to your path **before** `/usr/local/bin`

```
export PATH=/opt/ss:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/opt/ss:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

to make this permanent, add to the end of `~/.profile`

```
PATH=/opt/ss:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH does.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

and please do not just change the path (it will likely change more than just "ss"). Use

```
/bin/ss  -tpla
```

Comment: so the priority is the same as in `PATH` env variable?